# MS Access - Text field retuns the querys string instead of the query result value

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have tried a few variations, and all seem to give me the same result - so I am overlooking something pretty simple I think.

I have a text box for an account number, a search button, and a text box for the result of the search query.  However, when I hit search - the query itself gets added to the second text box instead of the expected result of 1 or 0.

This is my latest attempt, found on this site:

```
Private Sub SearchAcctNumber_Click()


Dim strsearch As String
Dim Task As String

If IsNull(Me.Text0) Or Me.Text0 = "" Then
   MsgBox "Please type in your account number.", vbOKOnly, "Acct Num Needed"
   Me.Text0.SetFocus
Else
    strsearch = Me.Text0.Value
    Task = "SELECT I_Ind FROM dbo_BC WHERE (([ACCOUNT_NUMBER] Like ""*" & Text0 & "*""))"
   Me.Text2 = Task

End If

End Sub
```

Is anyone able to help me see the error I am making?  It is driving me nuts that something so simple isn't working how I thought it should.

Edit:  Wanted to add that I've also tried DLookup and get the same result in other iterations of attempts at this.

Comment: It does that because you are telling the code to do that in the line `Me.Text2 = Task`, when you defined `Task = "SELECT I_Ind FROM dbo_BC WHERE (([ACCOUNT_NUMBER] Like ""*" & Text0 & "*""))"`

Comment: Check the function [DlookUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-dlookup-method-access). I think is exactly what you need to save the value you want in `Task`

Comment: Ok, now I read about your update and Dlookup. How did you test it? Can you post it?

Comment: It does not work when you use something like `Task = DLookup("[I_Ind]", "dbo_BC", " [ACCOUNT_NUMBER] like *" & Text0.Text & "*")`???

Comment: When I change it to the DLookup, like in your suggestion, I get a 'setfocust' error 2185.  I am researching why this is needed with Dlookup versus the other way, but thanks for your input so far!

Comment: Your code never actually runs a query or retrieves any data. It just creates a string that contains SQL code. What you are seeing is absolutely normal. If you want to be able to retrieve data from a `SELECT` query learn how to open a recordset and get results. `DLookup` will do when you are only looking for a single result like your case here. Finally, your query string is also wrong. `& Text0 &` shoule be `& Me.Text0 &`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to reconsider the `Like` approach in this case. Anyways, the issue is that you assign a string (the SQL command) to the textbox and this is what you see.

Try this instead:

---

```
Private Sub SearchAcctNumber_Click()

    If IsNull(Text0.Value) Then
       MsgBox "Please type in your account number.", vbOKOnly, "Acct Num Needed"
       Text0.SetFocus
       Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strCriteria As String

    strSearch = Text0.Value
    strCriteria = "ACCOUNT_NUMBER Like '*" & strSearch & "*'"

    Text2.Value = Nz(DLookup("I_Ind", "dbo_BC", strCriteria), "Not found...")

End Sub
```

You could also "search" while you type on `Text0`. Set the minimum number of characters before attempting to locate it.

---

```
Private Sub Text0_Change()
    If Len(Text0.Text) > 3 Then
        Text2.Value = Nz(DLookup("I_Ind", "dbo_BC", "ACCOUNT_NUMBER Like '*" & Text0.Text & "*'"), vbNullString)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion, thank you so much.  I've marked it as the answer and the code works as expected.  Interesting approach.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is, that you change `Text2` type to `combo box`. Then you set `Text2.recordsource = Task` and you refresh the displayed value with `Me.Text2.requery`.

Another way is to open a recordset, read the value, and set Text2 value.

```
Dim r as dao.recordset, db as dao.database  
set db = currentdb()  
set r=db.openrecordset(Task)  
Me.Text2 = r(0).value
Set r = Nothing
```